# How do I increase the size of the red, green, and blue circles using plt.plot()?

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I use the following code to plot dots on a graph:

```
plt.plot(x_array[peak],y_array[peak],'ro')
```

How do I increase the size of the red circle that is plotted?

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the size using `markersize`:

```
plt.plot(x_array[peak],y_array[peak],'ro', markersize=10)
```

- The default size is 6

More info [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot)